# Ember.js / Rails / Devise - Handling Validation Errors from Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise

Hiyo

I'm pretty new to ember - working on building an Ember front, Rails back authentication with Devise.  Trying to show server side errors on the Client...

I've read a bunch of stuff about this but nothing seems to work.

**Login Page is at /sessions/new**

Sessions New Template (Emblem.js)

```
Ember.TextField valueBinding="email" placeholder="Email" type="text"
= errors.email
```

Sessions New Route

```
SiloStore.SessionsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  model: -> @store.createRecord('session')

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', model)
```

Sessions New Controller

```
SiloStore.SessionsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend

  needs: ['admin']

  actions:{
    logIn: ->
      self = @
      content = @content

      @content.save().then(->
        self.get('controllers.admin').set('content', content);
        self.transitionToRoute 'admin.dashboard'
      )
  }
```

Sessions Controller (Rails)

```
render json: {
  errors: {
    email: ["invalid email or password"]
  }
}, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

JSON Error from Rails Server in Console

```
{"errors":{"email":["invalidemailorpassword"]}}
```

Now instead of my Error showing under the Ember.TextField in my template - I'm getting a big ugly red error that looks like this:

```
POST http://dev.siloarts.net:3000/api/v1/sessions 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
Error: The backend rejected the commit because it was invalid: {email: invalid email or password}
```

**Any Ideas??  I'm sure it's a dumb thing...**

Oh oh oh and here is my debug info:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0-beta.1+canary.011b67b8 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.5+canary.d9ce2a53 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

THANKYOU IN ADVANCE LOVE HUGH

Answer (score 1):

This error is also preventing errors structure binding. You can fix/patch it this way: call `person.save().catch(->)`always when you need to save. This will catch the error and do noting but one could still use `becameError:` and  `becameInvalid`on the model or just implement the function on its own. You can also change your model class as follows:

```
App.Model =  DS.Model.extend
  save: (catchErr=true) ->
    if catchErr
      fail = ->
        console.log('Save failed')
      retutn @_super().catch(fail)
    @_super()
```

Than change your base callas for a Person object

```
App.Person =  App.Model.extend 
...
```

And then when you need real catch use `person.save(false).catch(fn)`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error after upgrading. Downgrading to Ember 1.2.0 should solve your problem:)

Comment: Thanks Thomas but I wanna keep up to date with Ember... I needed to update to user the ActiveModelAdapter in my store...

Comment: Ah I see. Well you don't need to update Ember to have the ActiveModelAdapter, since it's actually in Ember Data. I'm using Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.4 and Ember 1.2.0 and it works perfectly fine with the ActiveModelAdapter. From what I can tell the error you encounter occurs with Ember >= 1.3.